how do i get this code to loop if the answer is wrong
how do I get this code to loop if the answer is wrong
    int myAns; 

    printf("If 10 is less than 13, the correct statment for is 10<13? write '1' for True and '0' for False: \n"); 
    scanf("%d", &myAns); 

    if (myAns == 1) { 
        printf("Correct.\n\nNext question\nIf 20 is more than 8, the correct statment for is 20<8? write '1' for True and '0' for False: \n"); 
    } else { 
        printf("Wrong, please try again.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    scanf("%d", &myAns); 

    if (myAns == 0) { 
        printf("Correct.\n\nNext question\nIf 25 is less than 100, the correct statment for is 25>100? write '1' for True and '0' for False: \n"); 
    } else { 
        printf("Wrong, please try again.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    scanf("%d", &myAns); 

    if (myAns == 0) { 
        printf("Correct.\n\nYou have completed the quiz!\n"); 
    } else { 
        printf("Wrong, please try again.\n");
    }

    return 0; 
}

I tried changing the value of return 0; but it did not come as it should

I think you should limit the number of attempts on any single question, so as you establish any loop, you should have an upper limit.  Your code always returns 0, regardless of whether the user gave the right answer or not.  You should either distinguish between success and failure or make the function return void (nothing).  Note that "statement" has two e's.  Phrases like "the correct statement for is 25>100" read somewhat peculiarly.  Maybe it should be "the correct statement for it is 25>100", though there are other ways it could be written.

Off topic: printing the next question in the same printf statement that prints Correct makes the code hard to read. IMO the next question should have its own printf after the check for correct answer.

This question is similar to: Input validation in C. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If you want to loop each question until a correct answer is provided you need a loop. I'd suggest using an infinite loop then breaking on the correct answer.
You also need to check for valid input by checking the return value from scanf.
for (;;) {
    int myAns; 

    printf("If 10 is less than 13, the correct statement for is 10<13? write '1' for True and '0' for False: \n"); 

    if (scanf("%d", &myAns) == 1 && myAns == 1) { 
        printf("Correct.\n"); 
        break;
    } else { 
        printf("Wrong, please try again.\n");
    }
}

You can then repeat this for each question.
You may wish to provide more detailed feedback in the event of invalid input.
for (;;) {
    int myAns; 

    printf("If 10 is less than 13, the correct statement for is 10<13? write '1' for True and '0' for False: \n"); 

    if (scanf("%d", &myAns) != 1 || !(myAns== 0 || myAns== 1)) {
        printf("Invalid input. Try again.\n");
        continue;
    }

    if (myAns == 1) { 
        printf("Correct.\n"); 
        break;
    } else { 
        printf("Wrong, please try again.\n");
    }
}

Further exercises:

Beware that this will leave the invalid input in the buffer to be read infinitely by scanf. A further exercise would be to replace use of scanf with fgets to read in a line of input and then parse myAns from that line.
Don't repeat yourself. Find a way to bundle questions and correct answers as structs and create an array of them that can be iterated.


This answer is based on @Chris's recommendation:

Don't repeat yourself. Find a way to bundle questions and correct answers as structs and create an array of them that can be iterated.

There are 3 examples of unification in this seemingly complex code at once:

Cyclic asking of questions (QUEST_ARR)
Iterating through all the elements of the array (foreach)
Output a question string with a different prefixes (pref)

#include <stdio.h>

#define foreach(item, array) \
    for(int keep = 1, count = 0, size = sizeof (array) / sizeof *(array); \
        keep && count != size; keep = !keep, count++) \
        for(item = (array) + count; keep; keep = !keep)

typedef struct { const char* text; int trueAns; } Question;
const char NEXT_QUEST_STR[] = "\nNext question:\n";
const char WRONG_ANSW_STR[] = "Wrong, please try again.\n";
const Question QUEST_ARR[] = {
    { "If 10 is less than 13, the correct statment for is 10<13?",   1 },
    { "If 20 is more than 8, the correct statment for is 20<8?",     0 },
    { "If 25 is less than 100, the correct statment for is 25>100?", 0 },
};

int main() {
    const char* pref = "";
    foreach (const Question* q, QUEST_ARR) {
        for (int myAns, ch;;) {
            printf("%s%s Write '1' for True and '0' for False: ", pref, q->text);
            int scanRes = scanf("%d", &myAns);
            while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
            if (scanRes == 1 && myAns == q->trueAns) {
                printf("Correct.\n");
                break;
            }
            pref = WRONG_ANSW_STR;
        }
        pref = NEXT_QUEST_STR;
    }
    return 0;
}


Surely the outer infinite for loop should be for (int i = 0; i < questArrLen; i++) and the if (++i >= questArraLen) break; statement can be dropped.

@JonathanLeffler, this is done to output the "Next question".

if (i > 0) puts("Next question"); at the top of the loop?

And how do you like this way?

IMO it's an overly complicated way to do something simple.

I added an explanation of why such an answer is better than a simple one. A beginner will write a simple code himself. But my goal is to instill in him a love of programming.

@KonstantinMakarov You don't get to love programming if someone shows you that simple things require complex solutions.

@4386427, thanks for the idea about the wrong answer string.

C has 3 loop statements (Iteration statements):

while loop
do while loop
for loop

The difference between while and do while is whether the check for "keep looping" is done before or after the loops statements. With while it's done before which means that the loops statements can be executed 0 to N times. With do while it's done after which means that the loops statements will be executed at least ones, i.e. the loops statements can be executed 1 to N times.
The for loop is the most complex of the 3 loop statements. Both with respect to syntax and how it's executed. But it's also the most powerful and the syntax helps you to avoid "stupid mistakes" as it forces you to think about things like "start condition", "stop condition" and "per loop updates". So a study of for loops is highly recommended.
However, to keep this simple, I'll use a do while. The reason for selecting do while over while is that we want to ask the question at least ones. That makes do while a perfect fit.
So the first simple approach is to wrap each of your questions into a do while so that the question will be repated until the user gives the correct answer.
int myAns;
const char* wrongStr;

// QUESTION #1
puts("Question:");
wrongStr = "";
do {
    printf("%s", wrongStr); // First time nothing will be printed.
                            // Afterwards it will print "Wrong, please ...
    wrongStr = "Wrong, please try again.\n";

    printf("If 10 is less than 13, the correct statment "
           "for is 10<13? write '1' for True and '0' for False: \n");

    scanf("%d", &myAns);   // BAD - SEE LATER

} while (myAns != 1);      // If the answer isn't correct (i.e 1)
                           // repeat the question
puts("Correct.\n"); 

// QUESTION #2
puts("Question:");
wrongStr = "";
do {
    printf("%s", wrongStr); // First time nothing will be printed.
                            // Afterwards it will print "Wrong, please ...
    wrongStr = "Wrong, please try again.\n";

    printf("If 25 is less than 100, the correct statment "
           "for is 25>100? write '1' for True and '0' for False: \n");

    scanf("%d", &myAns);   // BAD - SEE LATER

} while (myAns != 0);      // If the answer isn't correct (i.e 0)
                           // repeat the question
puts("Correct.\n"); 

// QUESTION #3
...
...

That's it. Now there is a loop around each question.
But isn't it a pain to repeat the nearly same code again and again? And for every new question, it has to be repeated again. Not good!
And the "correct answer" is hard coded into the while(...).  Not good!
In this case the solution for this is arrays. (In general it's often the case that loops and arrays are used together).
Put the "questions" and "correct answers" into arrays. This allows you to re-use the same code for all questions.
int myAns;
const char* wrongStr;

// Much better but not real good - see later
const char* question[] =
{
  "If 10 is less than 13, the correct statment for is 10<13? write '1' for True and '0' for False: \n",
  "If 20 is more than 8, the correct statment for is 20<8? write '1' for True and '0' for False: \n",
  "If 25 is less than 100, the correct statment for is 25>100? write '1' for True and '0' for False: \n"
};

// Much better but not real good - see later
int correctAns[] =
{
    1,
    0,
    0
};

size_t num_question = sizeof correctAns / sizeof correctAns[0];

for (size_t i = 0; i < num_question; ++i) {
    puts("Question:");
    wrongStr = "";
    do {
        printf("%s", wrongStr);
        wrongStr = "Wrong, please try again.\n";

        puts(question[i]);

        scanf("%d", &myAns);   // BAD - SEE LATER
    
    } while (myAns != correctAns[i]);
    puts("Correct.\n"); 
}

Now you don't have to repeat the same code for each question. And to add a new question, just extend the two arrays question and correctAns. No code change needed. That's nice...
But why 2 arrays? That feels bad. A question and the correct answer belongs together so they shouldn't be in separate arrays. It's difficult to see which correct answer belongs to which question. And you may extend one array and forget the other... bad.
To solve this, we need struct. With a struct we can group things that belong together into a single object. Like:
#include <stdio.h>

struct q_and_a {
    const char* question;
    int correctAns;
};

int main(void) {
    int myAns;
    const char* wrongStr;
    
    struct q_and_a qa[] =
    {
        {
            "If 10 is less than 13, the correct statment for is 10<13? write '1' for True and '0' for False: \n",
            1
        },
        {
            "If 20 is more than 8, the correct statment for is 20<8? write '1' for True and '0' for False: \n",
            0
        },
        {
            "If 25 is less than 100, the correct statment for is 25>100? write '1' for True and '0' for False: \n",
            0
        }
    };
    
    size_t num_question = sizeof qa / sizeof qa[0];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_question; ++i) {
        puts("Question:");
        wrongStr = "";
        do {
            printf("%s", wrongStr);
            wrongStr = "Wrong, please try again.\n";

            puts(qa[i].question);

            scanf("%d", &myAns);   // BAD - SEE LATER
        
        } while (myAns != qa[i].correctAns);
        puts("Correct.\n"); 
    }
    
    return 0;
}

Done.
SCANF IS BAD
As an end-note I'll recommend that you forget all about scanf. A statement like:
scanf("%d", &myAns);

are bad for a number of reasons. There is no check of the return value so you actually don't know whether a value was assigned to myAns. But worse... if the user gives some input which isn't valid for an integer, your program will enter an infinite loop as you don't have any code for removing "illegal input" from the input stream.
There are ways to solve those problems (just search stackoverflow and you'll find multiple examples).
However, a much better approach is to forget scanf and instead use fgets.
If you insists on using scanf then at least change it to:
        while(scanf("%d", &myAns) != 1) {
            getchar();
        }

It's better... but not perfect as stream errors and EOF isn't handled correctly.

while(scanf("%d", &myAns) != 1) { getchar(); } is not only an issue with stream errors, but an infinite loop on end-of-file.

@chux. Nice catch. Updated.
